# AWS Cognito Identiy - "{cognito-identity, us-east-2} was not found in region metadata"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito Identity to create users. I am following this (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html) tutorial.

Here's my code: `

public class testLogin extends AppCompatActivity{

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
String clientId = "########################";
String poolId = "############";
String clientSecret = "###############################";

CognitoUserPool userPool;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_login);

    userPool = new CognitoUserPool(getApplicationContext(), poolId, clientId, clientSecret, clientConfiguration);

    CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
    userAttributes.addAttribute("given_name", "test");
    userAttributes.addAttribute("email", "testEmail@gmail.com");

    userPool.signUpInBackground("testUserName", "TestPW2!#", userAttributes, null, signupCallback);

}
SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) {
        // Sign-up was successful

        // Check if this user (cognitoUser) needs to be confirmed
        if(!userConfirmed) {
            // This user must be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
            // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
            // Get the confirmation code from user
        }
        else {
            // The user has already been confirmed
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
        // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
    }
};
```

}`

And here is what Android Monitor is outputting:

```html
08-03 13:25:44.281 6299-6299/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-03 13:25:44.282 6299-6299/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-03 13:25:44.299 6299-6306/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-03 13:25:44.299 6299-6306/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-03 13:25:44.299 6299-6306/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-03 13:25:44.433 6299-6299/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.mathbattlestest-1/lib/x86
08-03 13:25:44.444 6299-6299/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-03 13:25:44.645 6299-6299/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-03 13:25:44.868 6299-6299/? I/AmazonWebServiceClient: {cognito-identity, us-east-2} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-identity.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'.
08-03 13:25:44.881 6299-6299/? I/AmazonWebServiceClient: {cognito-sync, us-east-2} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-sync.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'.
08-03 13:25:45.083 6299-6299/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
                                      
                                      [ 08-03 13:25:45.106  6299: 6317 D/         ]
                                      HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x99087e40, tid 6317
08-03 13:25:45.107 6299-6317/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-03 13:25:45.108 6299-6317/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
```

How do I fix this error: "I/AmazonWebServiceClient: {cognito-sync, us-east-2} was not found in region metadata..."

My current code does not add a new user (or anything at all) into my user pool.

Comment: Did you double check that that pool is for `us-east-2`?

Comment: Yes I did, I have had previous issues with us-east-2. I resolved my issue by switching everything to us-east-1